# Resizable frame in Gui

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

how to get non resizable `frame` in gui i confused about this because i am using `setLayout(new FlowLayout());` so if i drag the size of the `frame` the location of my `button` is going to disarrange . here is my code so far

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class aw extends JFrame
{
    private JTextField aw1;
    private JLabel aww;
    private JButton aw2;

    public aw()
    {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());


        aww = new JLabel("Enter Your Password");
        add(aww);

        aw1 = new JTextField(15);
        add(aw1);

        aw2 = new JButton("Enter");
        add(aw2);
    }
    public static void main(String args [])
    {
        aw v = new aw();

            v.setSize(200,200);
            v.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            v.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all the content into a `JPanel`, that would let you configure the `pack()` element, please ensure that you use an Empty Border. In the Object we have an accesor by `setResizable` set it to false.

Keep a note of rest and then use a Singleton thread model to run the Event-Dispatch Thread.

Thanks to AndrewThompson for his extra-ordinary knowledge that I was able to make the necessary updates

Answer (score 4):

I think `setResizable(false)` is what you're looking for

**SIDE NOTES**

- Also, instead of `setSize()`. You should just `pack()` the frame. You can use `EmptyBorder`s if you want empty space.
- If you *wanted*  the frame to be re-sizable and you want all the components centered when resizing, You could always wrap them all in a `JPanel`, then add the `JPanel` to the frame.
- Use Java naming convention. Class names start with capital letters.
- Run Swing apps form the Event Dispatch Thread, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Comment: @CoderShei I don't see any difference in the accepted answer that would warrant the un-accepting of this one in exchange for that one. The _only_ difference is that it was answered _after_ you already accepted this one. Other than that it looks no more than what my answer _already_ provided.